# Python ICMP Pinger

Tags: python, icmp

I'm trying to make an ICMP Pinger for class but I get this error when I try to compile it. I'm not sure what else to do, most of the code is a skeleton code from my textbook so I'm not entirely sure what's going wrong.

When I compile this code

```
from socket import *
import os
import sys
import struct
import time
import select
import binascii

ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST = 8

def checksum(str):
    csum = 0
    countTo = (len(str) / 2) * 2

    count = 0
    while count < countTo:
        thisVal = ord(str(str[count+1])) * 256 + ord(str(str[count]))
        csum = csum + thisVal
        csum = csum & 0xffffffff
        count = count + 2

    if countTo < len(str):
        csum = csum + ord(str[leb(str) - 1])
        csum = csum & 0xffffffff

    csum = (csum >> 16) + (csum & 0xffff)
    csum = csum + (csum >> 16)
    answer = ~csum
    answer = answer & 0xffff
    andswer = answer >> 8 | (answer << 8 & 0xff00)
    return answer

def recieveOnePing(mySocket, ID, timeout, destAddr):
    timeLeft = timeout

    while 1:
        startedSelect = time.time()
        whatReady = select.select([mySocket], [], [], timeLeft)
        howLongInSelect = (time.time() - startedSelect)
        if whatReady[0] == []: # Timeout
            return "Request timed out."
        timeRecieved = time.time()
        recPacket, addr = mySocket.recvfrom(1024)

        icmph = recPacket[20:28]
        type, code, checksum, pID, sq = struct.unpack("bbHHh", icmph)

        print ("The header received in the ICMP reply is ",type, code, checksum, pID, sq)
        if pID == ID:
            bytesinDbl = struct.calcsize("d")
            timeSent = struct.unpack("d", recPacket[28:28 + bytesinDbl])[0]
            rtt=timeReceived - timeSent

        print ("RTT is : ")
        return rtt

        timeLeft = timeLeft - howLongInSelect
        if timeLeft <= 0:
            return "Request timed out"

def sendOnePing(mySocket, destAddr, ID):
    myChecksum = 0
    header = struct.pack("bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0 , myChecksum, ID, 1)
    data = struct.pack("d", time.time())
    myChecksum = checksum(header + data)

    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        myChecksum = socket.htons(myChecksum) & 0xffff
    else:
        myChecksum = socket.htons(myChecksum)

    header = stuct.pack("bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0, myChecksum, ID, 1)
    packet = header + data

    mySocket.sendto(packet, (destAddr, 1))

def doOnePing(destAddr, timeout):
    icmp = getprotobyname("icmp")

    mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    myId = os.getpid() & 0xFFFF
    sendOnePing(mySocket, destAddr, myID)
    delay = recieveOnePing(mySocket, myID, timeout, destAddr)

    mySocket.close()
    return delay

def ping(host, timeout=1):
    dest = gethostbyname(host)
    print ("Pinging" + dest + "using Python:")
    print ("")
    while 1:
        delay = doOnePing(dest, timeout)
        print(delay)
        time.sleep(1)
    return delay

ping("www.google.com")
```

I get this error

```
File "ICMPPinger.py", line 17, in checksum
    thisVal = ord(str(str[count+1])) * 256 + ord(str(str[count]))
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable
```

Should I rename my variable? I'm not sure what this line is supposed to be doing and when I had it as

```
thisVal = ord(str[count+1]) * 256 + ord(str[count]))
```

I got the error:
    File "ICMPPinger.py", line 17, in checksum thisVal = ord(str[count+1]) * 256 + ord(str[count]) TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Comment: Thank you Mahesh for answering my original problem, I edited it for my current problem now

Answer (score 0):

In def doOnePing() you have defined variable with name `myId` but you're passing variable as name `myID` which is why you get the undefined variable error. So as fix replace `myId` with `myID` as follows while defining the variable:

```
myID = os.getpid() & 0xFFFF
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error though where it says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ICMPPinger.py", line 99, in <module>
    ping("www.google.com")
  File "ICMPPinger.py", line 94, in ping
    delay = doOnePing(dest, timeout)
  File "ICMPPinger.py", line 83, in doOnePing
    sendOnePing(mySocket, destAddr, myID)
  File "ICMPPinger.py", line 65, in sendOnePing
    myChecksum = checksum(header + data)
  File "ICMPPinger.py", line 17, in checksum
    thisVal = ord(str[count+1]) * 256 + ord(str[count])
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Comment: replace `thisVal = ord(str[count+1]) * 256 + ord(str[count])` with `thisVal = ord(str(str[count+1])) * 256 + ord(str(str[count]))`  which will type cast int to string

Comment: I tried that and it says TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable

Comment: @ElliottLivingston you use `str` as variable to keeps you bytes so you don't have access to method `str()` . When you do `str()` then it executes `your_bytes()` and it gives `'bytes' object is not callable`

Comment: So should I rename my variable? I'm not even sure what this line is supposed to do and what those methods are doing

Comment: @Elliott Livingston  Please don't revise your question in the comments.  First, please ask one question at a time.  Often if answering that question leads to a new error, best to accept the answer and ask a new question.  You're trying to write questions that are useful for the future.

Comment: Even if you do decide that you don't need to ask a new question, then go edit the question so it stands on its own without comments.  It's reasonable to note in the appropriate comment thread that you've edited.